# Multiple endpoints & concrete objects VS single endpoint & dynamic object

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, casting, controller

Given a class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeId { get; set; }

    public object Content { get; set; }
}
```

And an endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task SomeTask(SomeClass entity)
{
    await _someService.Process(entity);
}
```

The Content property would be different depending on SomeId value (it could be arrays, tuples, or some structs). This difference is known at compile time. SomeId ranges from 1 to 20 and new variants can be introduced.

Now the question is - what would be better:

1. Have 20+ endpoints for each possible SomeId value. Instead of using object type for Content I would use concrete class definitions.
2. Have single endpoint + factory to decide how to process SomeId that has arrived. Factory will have to explicitly cast object to a concrete type.

I think that 2nd option is better but a bit uncertain about having to resort to casting

Comment: You want a factory, but you don't have to cast anything. Use a dictionary in your factory setup that will create a new instance of the object you want depending on the value of SomeId. All you'll need is an interface and a class for each Content object. (ie: Dictonary<int, IContent> contentMapping = new Dictonary<int, IContent>();)

Comment: I don't think I can have it as interface: Deserialization of interface types is not supported

Comment: @GHDevOps could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IContent
{
   object SomeTask();
}

public class MyTuple : IContent
{
   public object SomeTask()
   {
      return new Tuple<string, int>("My Tuple", 1);
   }
}

public class ContentFactory
{
   private Dictionary<int, IContent> mapper = new Dictionary<int, IContent>();

   public ContentFactory()
   {
     mapper.add(1, new MyTuple());
   }

   public object GetSomeTask(int SomeId)
   {
      return mapper[SomeId].SomeTask();
   }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var cf = new ContentFactory();
   var tup = cf.GetSomeTask(1);
}
```

So for each object type create a new class and inherit IContent (ie: MyArray, MyCollection, etc...)